# Android style two items selected

Tags: android, view, menu, navigation, drawer

i've a problem in android. When i try to select first item at startup, and select other item except the first item so i've two items selected. This is my code. I've added navigationView.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(R.id.menu_program, 0) to select the first item but i think that the problem comes from this (i don't know). Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    actionBarDrawerToggle = setupActionBarDrawerToggle();
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    setupNavigationViewContent(navigationView);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        navigationView.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(R.id.menu_program, 0);
    }
}

private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupActionBarDrawerToggle() {
    return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
}

private void setupNavigationViewContent(NavigationView navigationView) {

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            selectNavigationViewItem(item);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void selectNavigationViewItem(MenuItem item) {
    /*if (lastItem == null) {
        lastItem = item;
        item.setChecked(true);
        Log.e("TAG", "selectNavigationViewItem: "+lastItem);
    } else {
        lastItem.setChecked(false);
    }*/

    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_program:
            fragmentClass = Fragment1.class;
            break;

        case R.id.menu_visitor:
            fragmentClass = Fragment2.class;
            break;

        case R.id.menu_partner:
            fragmentClass = Fragment3.class;
            break;

        case R.id.menu_about:
            fragmentClass = Fragment4.class;
            break;

        case R.id.menu_team:
            fragmentClass = Fragment5.class;
            break;

        case R.id.menu_contact:
            fragmentClass = Fragment6.class;
            break;

        default:
            fragmentClass = Fragment1.class;
    }

    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout_content, fragment).commit();

    item.setChecked(true);
    setTitle(item.getTitle());

    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
}

@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

Comment: did you tried  <group android:checkableBehavior="single"> inside your menu.xml ?

Comment: ya, as i say below the problem is solved but now when i try to rotate the first item isn't checked. cos the onCreate is called and savedInstance isn't null

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing item.setChecked(true), you have to uncheck previous one.
Declare a MenuItem menuItem outside functions and replace your item.setChecked(true) with following code:

```
if(menuItem != null)
    menuItem.setChecked(false);
menuItem = item;
menuItem.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: Thanks but i've an other problem. When i try to rotate in landscape the first item is not checked.